# Another Gaussian sum

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, gauss-sums

I'm trying to evaluate

$$
\sum_{m'}\exp(-i\pi(m'+\alpha)/M)
$$

where $\alpha=0,1,\dots,2M$. There are two questions. The first is the claim is that if $M$ is even and

$$
\sum_{m'=1}^M\exp(-i\pi(m'+\alpha)/M) = \sqrt{M}e^{-i\pi/4}.
$$

First, I don't understand how to get rid of $\alpha$. If I do the numerics, this integer doesn't appear to play any role, but I don't understand why because if I set $m=m'+\alpha$ the sum gets shifted and one gets an extra term.

The second is, if $M$ is instead odd and $N=(M-1)/2$ how does one evaluate

$$
\sum_{m'=-N}^N\exp(-i\pi(m'+\alpha)/M) = \;?.
$$

I feel that one can use either [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323774/how-to-prove-a-generalized-gauss-sum-formula) or the second formula in exercise 43, Chapt. 10 from [Askey](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521789885) but I can't see how.